# php session data -- codeigniter -- facebook api

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm having problems with passing session information from one function to another function.

```
public function xpto() {
       $this->load->library('session');
       $session_id = $this->session->all_userdata();
       $fb_pages = array(
            'fb_page' => $result_querypageidlink[0]['link']
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata($fb_pages);

       $this->load->library('fbconnect');
       $data = array(
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('main/handle_facebook_login_users'),
            'scope' => 'email, 
            user_birthday, 
            user_hometown, 
            user_location'
       );
   redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
}
```

Other Function called in 'redirect_uri':

```
public function handle_facebook_login_users() {

$this->load->library('session');
$all_userdata = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

When i print $all_userdata doesnt show me the info i added and the xpto function.
For some reason when i added session information (xpto function) and if i printed (in the function, is already there -- so it's working) but when i print in the second function, doesnt show me that info.

Answer (score 0):

Set session like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('fb_page', $fb_pages);
```

Retrieve like this:

```
$fb_page = $this->session->userdata('fb_page');
```

**Edit:**

```
public function xpto() {
       $this->load->library('session');
       $session_id = $this->session->all_userdata();
       $fb_pages = array(
            'fb_page' => $result_querypageidlink[0]['link']
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('fb_pages', $fb_pages); #set the session

       $this->load->library('fbconnect');
       $data = array(
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('main/handle_facebook_login_users'),
            'scope' => 'email, 
            user_birthday, 
            user_hometown, 
            user_location'
       );
   redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
}



public function handle_facebook_login_users() {
    $this->load->library('session');                     #Load the session in the autoload.php
    $fb_pages   = $this->session->userdata('fb_pages');  #retrieve the session
}
```

Comment: Not really. Still the same

Comment: Nop, doesnt work anyway. I added ob_start(); after session loading, cause it was giving errors.

But i cant see the info inside session with echo

Comment: look my edit. if i add "all_userdata" instead of "userdata", already show me the array with session information, but 'fb_pages' doenst show